# get the recently added item from sitecore

Tags: sitecore

If I create an item in sitecore from code behind using following code [as shown in example](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems2.aspx) under the heading **Creating items**:

```
//Now we can add the new item as a child to the parent
    parentItem.Add("NewItemName", template);
```

And then in order to get the this newly added item from sitecore database what I should do? Because I don't know the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new item will be returned by the add method.

Eg.

```
Item newItem = parentItem.Add("NewItemName", template);
```